# Scroll in a treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a treeview inside a tabitem. I want to add a scrollbar around the treeview. I have modified my xaml as below - added a scrollview around the treeview but the scrollbar never appears

```
                        <TabControl  Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Background="White">
                            <TabItem Header="TAB" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TabItem.Resources>
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" 
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildrenList}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" >
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                </TabItem.Resources>
                                <ScrollViewer Name="scroll1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                                    <TreeView Name="SymbolsTreeView" BorderThickness="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=scroll1, Path=ActualHeight}">
                                    <TreeViewItem Header="Symbols" IsExpanded="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ParentList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}">
                                    </TreeViewItem>
                                </TreeView>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </TabItem>
                        </TabControl>
```

Any idea anyone please?

Comment: Try setting the height of the treeview or the tabitem, and see if it helps, most likely it just doesn't activate because it can't know the exact height.

Comment: That does not help. Please note that I have put the scroll height as binding in the treeview height

Comment: When you say that doesn't help, do you mean it doesn't work or that you haven't tried it because you've bound the height already?

Comment: @goobering I tried setting the height to Auto both in Tabitem and Treeview after removing the binding but I still did not get a scrollbar in the treeview

Comment: Auto might not cut it - try setting Height to a fixed pixel height.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` as `Auto`. Meaning the scroll bar will be visible only when there is a need for it. If you want it to be visible always then set them to `Visible`.

Check this sample out. I have modified your code.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl  Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="White">
            <TabItem Header="TAB">
                <TabItem.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" 
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildrenList}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" >
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TabItem.Resources>
                <ScrollViewer Name="scroll1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <TreeView Name="SymbolsTreeView" BorderThickness="0" >
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Symbols" IsExpanded="True" Name="TV"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}">
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </TreeView>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace Demo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<DemoData> list = new List<DemoData>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                var data = new DemoData () {Name = "Data_HorzontallyLongData-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Almost--------------------------------Done." + i};
                data.ChildrenList = new List<DemoData>();
                for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                {
                    data.ChildrenList.Add(new DemoData() { Name = "Children_"+ i +"_"+ j});
                }
                list.Add(data);
            }
            TV.ItemsSource = list;
        }
    }

    public class DemoData
    {
        public List<DemoData> ChildrenList { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```